# What is the spell cast by Professor McGonagall to protect Hogwarts from Death Eaters and Dementors?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

In this scene, Professor McGonagall and several other teachers aim their wands at the sky and create a defensive dome over Hogwarts.

What is the spell?

If it is not *Expecto Patronum*, then why does it deter Dementors?

Answer (score 2):

In the book, the only spell we can see used is *Protego horribilis*, by Flitwick. But there isn't a single spell, but instead a mix of them.

> 'I can act from here', said Flitwick, and although he could barely see
> out of it, he pointed his wand through the smashed window and started
> muttering incantations of great complexity. Harry heard a weird
> rushing noise, as though Flitwick had unleashed the power of the wind
> into the grounds.
>
> <...>
>
> '... *Protego horribilis* - the diadem of Ravenclaw?' squeaked Flitwick.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows. Chapter thirty: The Sacking of Severus Snape</sub>

In the movies, as far as I can tell, there is no explicit spell used. Thus, I'm afraid we can't know which spells are used in that moment.

---

About your second part of the question, we can safely assume that *Expecto Patronum* wasn't cast, since that spell doesn't produce a durable shield, and if properly executed, produces a visible corporeal animal form, which wasn't shown in the movie, nor mentioned in the book.

Besides that, *Expecto Patronum* isn't the only spell that can be used to deal with Dementors, as we can see in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*.

> Harry fully expected to receive low marks on his, because he had disagreed with Snape on the best way to tackle Dementors, but he did not care.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*. Chapter twenty-one: The Unknowable Room.</sub>

Therefore, it isn't a stretch to think that a protective charm could protect you from Dementors to some degree, and Flitwick was using high-complexity protective charms that evidently could stop Dementors.